# Stata: append by ID and time stamp

Tags: stata

I have two datasets. One dataset here
[image: dataset 1 screenshot]
contains information on product assortment at grocery store/day level. This data reflects all the products that were available at a store in a given day.

Another data set
[image: dataset 2 screenshot] contains data on individuals who visited those stores on a given day.

As you can see in screenshot 2 the same person (highlighted, `panid=1101758`) only bought 2 products: `Michelob` and `Sam Adams` in week `1677 2` at store `234140`, whereas we know that overall 4 options were available to that individual in that store on that same day, i.e. 2 additional `Budweisers` (screenshot 1, highlighted obs.)

I need to merge/append these two datasets at the store/day for each individual in a way that the final data set shows that a person made those two purchases and in addition there were two more that were available to that individual at that store/day. Thus, that specific individual will have 4 observations - 2 purchased and 2 more available options. I have various stores, days, and individuals.

```
input store day brand
1 1 "Bud"
1 1 "Bud"
1 1 "Michelob"
1 1 "Sam Adams"
1 1 "Coors"
end


input hh store day brand
1 1 1 "Michelob"
1 1 1 "Sam Adams"
2 1 1 "Bud"
2 1 1 "Bud"
3 1 1 "Coors"
end
```

In the Stata code above you can see that it was another individual who purchased 2 Budweisers. For that individual a similar action has to also take place, where it can be shown that the individual had 4 options to choose from (Michelob, Sam Adams, Budweiser, Budweiser) but they ended up choosing only 2 Budweisers.

Here is the example of the end result I would like to receive:

```
input hh store day brand choice
1 1 1 "Michelob" 1
1 1 1 "Sam Adams" 1
1 1 1 "Bud" 0
1 1 1 "Bud" 0
1 1 1 "Coors" 0

2 1 1 "Bud" 1
2 1 1 "Bud" 1
2 1 1 "Michelob" 0
2 1 1 "Sam Adams" 0
2 1 1 "Coors" 0

3 1 1 "Coors" 1
3 1 1 "Michelob" 0
3 1 1 "Sam Adams" 0
3 1 1 "Bud" 0
3 1 1 "Bud" 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the example data. Could you also show an example of your desired outcome?

Comment: You need to create a `choice` variable in each dataset and then `append`.

Comment: Thank you, I see what you mean - this command might not work because **appending** will not create the full choice set for each individual. I am updating my example to illustrate that.

Comment: `fillin` could help.

Comment: Fillin - for this example, the fillin would be for hh/store/day level?

Comment: I have also looked at commands cross, joinby, append, merge - none of those return the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it. It involves creating an indicator for repeated products within store and day, using joinby to create all possible combinations between hh and products by store and day, and finally a merge to get the choice variable.

```
// Import hh data
clear
input hh store day str9 brand
1 1 1 "Michelob"
1 1 1 "Sam Adams"
2 1 1 "Bud"
2 1 1 "Bud"
3 1 1 "Coors"
end

// Create number of duplicate products for merging
bysort store day brand: gen n_brand = _n
gen choice = 1

tempfile hh hh_join
save `hh'

// Create dataset for use with joinby to create all possible combinations
// of hh and products per day/store
drop brand n_brand choice
duplicates drop
save `hh_join'

// Import store data
clear
input store day str9 brand
1 1 "Bud"
1 1 "Bud"
1 1 "Michelob"
1 1 "Sam Adams"
1 1 "Coors"
end

// Create number of duplicate products for merging
bysort store day brand: gen n_brand = _n

// Create all possible combinations of hh and products per day/store
joinby store day using `hh_join'
order hh store day brand n_brand
sort hh store day brand n_brand

// Merge with hh data to get choice variable
merge 1:1 hh store day brand n_brand using `hh'
drop _merge

// Replace choice with 0 if missing
replace choice = 0 if missing(choice)

list, noobs sepby(hh)
```

And the result:

```
. list, noobs sepby(hh)

  +-------------------------------------------------+
  | hh   store   day       brand   n_brand   choice |
  |-------------------------------------------------|
  |  1       1     1         Bud         1        0 |
  |  1       1     1         Bud         2        0 |
  |  1       1     1       Coors         1        0 |
  |  1       1     1    Michelob         1        1 |
  |  1       1     1   Sam Adams         1        1 |
  |-------------------------------------------------|
  |  2       1     1         Bud         1        1 |
  |  2       1     1         Bud         2        1 |
  |  2       1     1       Coors         1        0 |
  |  2       1     1    Michelob         1        0 |
  |  2       1     1   Sam Adams         1        0 |
  |-------------------------------------------------|
  |  3       1     1         Bud         1        0 |
  |  3       1     1         Bud         2        0 |
  |  3       1     1       Coors         1        1 |
  |  3       1     1    Michelob         1        0 |
  |  3       1     1   Sam Adams         1        0 |
  +-------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Hi Wouter! Thank you very much for your input.

Comment: Dear Wouter - this code unfortunately doesn't work on the real data. The last merging step doesn't work. I have tracked every singe step of the code and discovered that the step joinby in "Create all possible combinations of hh and products per day/store" leads to the creation of many duplicates in the real data set. Thus, merge 1:1 leads to an error. It is strange because the toy data set seems to be an accurate representation of the real data.

Comment: So it looks like the problem lies with `joinby`. Your `using` dataset for joinby should only contain three variables, store, day and panid, is this the case? Otherwise it's hard to tell what's wrong without seeing the data. It would be easier of you could post an example of your real data using `dataex`.